# линия не меняет цвет

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qss

[image: Линия]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить цвет этой линии?

Если задать цвет через **`color`**, то не реагирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, попробуйте так:

```
background-color: #f00;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как сделать его серым цветом, таким тусклым

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер  попробуйте `background-color: #ccc;` или выберите цвет какой вам нравится https://colorhunt.co/ Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour